# Deploying django media files to heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku, deployment

I am storing my image name that is uoloaded in database of postgres when deploying on heroku.

In that case i am calling it from my views.py. The image name with media url in my development.

What are the steps that i can follow to get this done? To upload the media in heroku as it is not found after upload. 
I have seen every blog and every page of stack overflow also. 
Please help

Comment: Heroku doesn't allow to store user-generated media (non-static files) on their dynos, see https://help.heroku.com/K1PPS2WM/why-are-my-file-uploads-missing-deleted

Comment: But, if i make use of S3 . How can i do that , there must be some steps to do this. I have created my bucket. I am able to move my files to AWS bucket but not able to identify what to write in MEDIA_ROOT and MEDIA_URL for user image uploads in my settings.py , models.py and urls.py. Please help me with some steps.